# Sticking few menu items to the bottom of a Menu in Mui Menu

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, menu

[image]I am using the menu from mui, and I want to stick some options of the menu items (like logout and user details) to the bottom of the screen as the menu opens up.

Here is my code

```
// MenuComponent.tsx
import {
  Box,
  List,
  ListItemIcon,
  ListItemText,
  Menu,
  MenuItem,
  Typography,
  useMediaQuery,
  useTheme,
} from "@mui/material";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

import { SvgArray } from "../../common/svgIcons";
import useMenuStore from "../../store/menuDataStore";

type MenuComponentProps = {
  anchorEl: HTMLElement | null;
  open: boolean;
  handleClose: () => void;
  menuItemId: string;
  menuItemName: string;
};

const MenuComponent: React.FC<MenuComponentProps> = ({
  anchorEl,
  open,
  handleClose,
  menuItemId,
  menuItemName,
}) => {
  const theme = useTheme();

  const is_heigth_less_800 = useMediaQuery("(max-height:800px)");
  const is_heigth_less_900 = useMediaQuery("(max-height:900px)");
  const is_heigth_less_1000 = useMediaQuery("(max-height:1000px)");
  const is_between_lg_and_xl = useMediaQuery(
    theme.breakpoints.between("lg", "xl")
  );

  const { menuItems } = useMenuStore();

  const selectedMenuItem = menuItems.find((item) => item.id === menuItemId);
  console.log(selectedMenuItem);

  const isBelowLG = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down("lg"));
  const isHeightLess = useMediaQuery("(max-height:900px)");

  const MenuContainerWrapper = styled(Box)({
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    height: "100%",
  });

  const LogoutContainerWrapper = styled(Box)({
    marginTop: "auto",
    paddingBottom: 35,
  });

  const MenuContainer = styled(Box)({
    flexGrow: 1,
    overflowY: "auto",
  });

  const LogoutContainer = styled(Box)({
    // position: "fixed",
    // bottom: 0,
    // textAlign: "center",
    // paddingBottom: 35,
    // display: "flex",
    // flexDirection: "column",
    // alignItems: "center",

    //paddingTop: `calc(100vh - 0.5px)`,
    // paddingBottom: "calc(90vh-0.5px)",
    paddingTop: is_heigth_less_800
      ? "170px"
      : is_heigth_less_900
      ? "230px"
      : is_heigth_less_1000
      ? "330px"
      : "500px",
    marginLeft: "8px",
    textAlign: "center",
    // paddingBottom: 35,
  });

  const MenuItemContainer = styled(Box)({
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
  });

  return (
    <Menu
      id="basic-menu"
      MenuListProps={{
        "aria-labelledby": "fade-button",
      }}
      sx={{
        // height: "100vh",
        "& .MuiPopover-paper": {
          width: isBelowLG ? "280px" : is_between_lg_and_xl ? "300px" : "320px",
          height: "calc(100% - 0.1px) ",
        },
      }}
      classes={{ paper: is_heigth_less_900 ? "menu-paper1" : "menu-paper" }}
      anchorOrigin={{
        vertical: "center",
        horizontal: "left",
      }}
      anchorEl={anchorEl}
      open={open}
      onClose={handleClose}
    >
      <MenuContainerWrapper>
        <MenuContainer id="menucontainer">
          <Typography
            id="menu-heading"
            variant="h6"
            sx={{ pl: 3, pr: 2, pt: 1, marginBottom: 4 }}
          >
            {menuItemName}
          </Typography>

          {selectedMenuItem?.subMenuItems?.map((item) => (
            <MenuItem onClick={handleClose} key={item.id}>
              <MenuItemContainer sx={{ marginTop: "6px" }}>
                <ListItemIcon
                  sx={{
                    color: theme.palette.primary.main,
                    //  marginBottom: "5px",
                    marginLeft: "5px",

                    "& svg": {
                      fontSize: isHeightLess ? "24px" : "30px",
                    },
                  }}
                >
                  {/* <InboxOutlined
                  style={{ flex: "0 0 30px", marginLeft: "3px" }}
                /> */}
                  {React.createElement(SvgArray[item.icon], {})}
                </ListItemIcon>
                <Box sx={{ marginTop: "2px", paddingBottom: "15px" }}>
                  <Typography
                    variant="body1"
                    style={{ flex: "1 1 auto", marginLeft: "10px" }}
                    color={theme.palette.text.secondary}
                  >
                    {item.title}
                  </Typography>
                </Box>
              </MenuItemContainer>
            </MenuItem>
          ))}

          {/* <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>
          <MenuItemContainer>
            <ListItemIcon
              sx={{
                color: theme.palette.primary.main,
              }}
            >
              <InboxOutlined style={{ flex: "0 0 30px", marginLeft: "3px" }} />
            </ListItemIcon>
            <Typography
              variant="body1"
              style={{ flex: "1 1 auto", marginLeft: "10px" }}
              color={theme.palette.text.secondary}
            >
              Resource Configuration
            </Typography>
          </MenuItemContainer>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>
          <MenuItemContainer>
            <ListItemIcon
              sx={{
                color: theme.palette.primary.main,
              }}
            >
              <InboxOutlined style={{ flex: "0 0 30px", marginLeft: "3px" }} />
            </ListItemIcon>
            <Typography
              variant="body1"
              style={{ flex: "1 1 auto", marginLeft: "10px" }}
              color={theme.palette.text.secondary}
            >
              Resource Configuration
            </Typography>
          </MenuItemContainer>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>
          <MenuItemContainer>
            <ListItemIcon
              sx={{
                color: theme.palette.primary.main,
              }}
            >
              <InboxOutlined style={{ flex: "0 0 30px", marginLeft: "3px" }} />
            </ListItemIcon>
            <Typography
              variant="body1"
              style={{ flex: "1 1 auto", marginLeft: "10px" }}
              color={theme.palette.text.secondary}
            >
              Resource Configuration
            </Typography>
          </MenuItemContainer>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>
          <MenuItemContainer>
            <ListItemIcon
              sx={{
                color: theme.palette.primary.main,
              }}
            >
              <InboxOutlined style={{ flex: "0 0 30px", marginLeft: "3px" }} />
            </ListItemIcon>
            <Typography
              variant="body1"
              style={{ flex: "1 1 auto", marginLeft: "10px" }}
              color={theme.palette.text.secondary}
            >
              Resource Configuration
            </Typography>
          </MenuItemContainer>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>
          <MenuItemContainer>
            <ListItemIcon
              sx={{
                color: theme.palette.primary.main,
              }}
            >
              <InboxOutlined style={{ flex: "0 0 30px", marginLeft: "3px" }} />
            </ListItemIcon>
            <Typography
              variant="body1"
              style={{ flex: "1 1 auto", marginLeft: "10px" }}
              color={theme.palette.text.secondary}
            >
              Resource Configuration
            </Typography>
          </MenuItemContainer>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>
          <MenuItemContainer>
            <ListItemIcon
              sx={{
                color: theme.palette.primary.main,
              }}
            >
              <InboxOutlined style={{ flex: "0 0 30px", marginLeft: "3px" }} />
            </ListItemIcon>
            <Typography
              variant="body1"
              style={{ flex: "1 1 auto", marginLeft: "10px" }}
              color={theme.palette.text.secondary}
            >
              Resource Configuration
            </Typography>
          </MenuItemContainer>
        </MenuItem> */}
        </MenuContainer>

        <LogoutContainer id="logoutcontainer">
          <MenuItem>
            <List
              sx={{
                display: "flex",
                flexDirection: "column",
                justifyContent: "center",
                alignItems: "center",
              }}
            >
              <ListItemText>
                <Typography variant="body1">Sam Smith</Typography>
              </ListItemText>
              <ListItemText>
                <Typography variant="body1">Admin</Typography>
              </ListItemText>
              <ListItemText>
                <Typography variant="body1">Abc Company</Typography>
              </ListItemText>
            </List>
          </MenuItem>
          <MenuItem>
            <Typography variant="body1" color={theme.palette.text.secondary}>
              Logout
            </Typography>
          </MenuItem>
        </LogoutContainer>
      </MenuContainerWrapper>
    </Menu>
  );
};

export default MenuComponent;
```

Right now I am using breakpoints to keep the items of the logout container at the bottom of the screen, this seems like a very crude method. Is there any way to achieve this nicely using flexbox within the menu? I tried a few things but nothing seems to work. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Can you please provide a drawing or some artificial representation of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @L_Cleo I have added the image, I want the Sam Smith, Admin ang logout part to stick at the bottom of the menu